# Activity list view display different data (String array) on click of listitem

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have an activity which contains `listview`, when click on any list item, i want to display same activity with `listview` with different data and so on.

When i click on back button i need to display same activity listview with old data.

Is it possible? or is there is any other way to achieve this. I dont want to create any new activities or fragments for this?

Thanks
KrishIndia

Answer (score 0):

on click of list item just set new adapter or new data and call notifyDataSetChanged()

and for backpress  override onBackPressed() and handle accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can write the function such that each time you click an item, it generates the list, assigns the data to your adapter and attaches it to your list view of choice.

If fetching the data won't be expensive for you, you could use only one adapter (array adapter or list adapter or simple adapter should be fine) and just re-assign it each time.  (Ex. If you were listing files in a directory, inside your `onClick()` function you would have some function declaration like `list_items(directoryName)` that you would call each time.  That function would declare and set an adapter for your data.)

If you are concerned about the expense of re-fetching the data, just store multiple adapters (outside your `onClick()` function) and set them to your list view as needed.

Answer (score -1):

Maintain separate adapter for each new data. When you want to return back just pass the relevent adapter object to that list view